# Import and select data from Table from nhl.com

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm a beginner in Python and I just started again a project that I put on the back burner for a while, and basically, I need to import data from a table on nhl.com.

I had my old code (about 1.5 year-old) but the display and general format of the page has changed since and it doesn't work anymore.

The table that I work from is in regard of Powerplay at home.

```
The URL is: http://www.nhl.com/stats/teams?report=powerplay&reportType=season&seasonFrom=20202021&seasonTo=20202021&gameType=2&homeRoad=H&filter=gamesPlayed,gte,1&sort=powerPlayPct&page=0&pageSize=50

The API (if I got it correctly is): https://api.nhle.com/stats/rest/en/team/powerplay?isAggregate=false&isGame=false&sort=%5B%7B%22property%22:%22powerPlayPct%22,%22direction%22:%22DESC%22%7D%5D&start=0&limit=50&factCayenneExp=gamesPlayed%3E=1&cayenneExp=gameTypeId=2%20and%20homeRoad=%22H%22%20and%20seasonId%3C=20202021%20and%20seasonId%3E=20202021
```

What I wanna be able to extract is:

```
1) Team
2) PP%
```

(first and before-last column)

I know this one is very easy for most people here, but I've been stuck for a little while now, and any kind of help would be appreciated.

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can load the data from the API URL with this example:

```
import requests


url = 'https://api.nhle.com/stats/rest/en/team/powerplay?isAggregate=false&isGame=false&sort=%5B%7B%22property%22:%22powerPlayPct%22,%22direction%22:%22DESC%22%7D%5D&start=0&limit=50&factCayenneExp=gamesPlayed%3E=1&cayenneExp=gameTypeId=2%20and%20homeRoad=%22H%22%20and%20seasonId%3C=20202021%20and%20seasonId%3E=20202021'
data = requests.get(url).json()

for i in data['data']:
    print('{:<30} {:.2f}'.format(i['teamFullName'], i['powerPlayPct']*100))
```

Prints:

```
Washington Capitals            45.16
Carolina Hurricanes            38.64
Boston Bruins                  38.46
Chicago Blackhawks             33.33
New York Islanders             30.30
Winnipeg Jets                  28.95
Dallas Stars                   28.85
Los Angeles Kings              28.57
Edmonton Oilers                28.12
Pittsburgh Penguins            25.81
Toronto Maple Leafs            25.58
Buffalo Sabres                 24.39
Vancouver Canucks              23.64
Calgary Flames                 23.25
Colorado Avalanche             22.45
Tampa Bay Lightning            21.62
Florida Panthers               21.62
Montréal Canadiens             21.43
San Jose Sharks                21.43
Ottawa Senators                20.93
Columbus Blue Jackets          20.00
Philadelphia Flyers            19.15
Vegas Golden Knights           17.95
Arizona Coyotes                16.07
St. Louis Blues                13.64
Nashville Predators            13.33
New York Rangers               12.24
New Jersey Devils              8.57
Minnesota Wild                 6.06
Detroit Red Wings              5.56
Anaheim Ducks                  4.76
```

Comment: Wow!! Thanx a lot!  It's working perfectly. Not sure I understand completely your last line though, especially that part: {:<30} {:.2f}. Also, how was it able to link 'teamFullName' and 'powerPlayPct' with the actual valid data? I don't see it in the API and I'm wondering how it could identify the proper data with these set names?

Comment: @ffspider `{:<30} {:.2f}` is string formating syntax. The data for each team is stored in list `data['data']`.

Comment: Thanx a lot for the clarifications!